# How to declare automatic properties of get and set as we do in C# but using VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Kinda new to Visual Basic.

You know that in C# we would write for example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Age {get; set;} 
}
```

I need to do something like that in order to use a class for capture some data and then create a list of this object type. But, how I write a simple Get, Set class in Visual Basic?? Any way to achieve this as simple as we do in C#????? Thank you!!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293589.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are no curly braces, nor is there an explicit get; set;

```
Public Property Age As Integer
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293589.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it as public:

`Public Age As Integer = 0`

Comment: Valid VB, but ain't no property.

Comment: When you're using default get/set there is no real difference

Comment: It absolutely DOES matter!  One is a property and one is a field with very real implications! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/09/04/properties-vs-fields-why-does-it-matter-jonathan-aneja.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
  Private _Age as Integer

Public Property Age() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Age 
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Age = value
        End Set
    End Property
```